# How to set site in maintenance mode trough shell-script?

Tags: bash, .htaccess, deployment, shell

For my next project I will use automatic deployments with git. I can run a shellscript before and after deployment.
Is it possible to set "maintenance" automatically with shell?

In my .htaccess then I would check if a server variable is set to deployment or not to do the rewrite to maintenance?

Is this possible and how should I handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "maintainance mode"? Should the web server be taken offline, or the user be redirected to a special page or something else? Should it be implemented in script code or in the web server software?

Comment: Not offline but a temporary rewriterule for a "landing page" with keeping the url he was requesting so a refresh of his page is taking the user where he wants to be (after deployment)

Answer (score 1):

You could have the .htaccess check for the existence of a file with a certain name, and if it exists, redirect to a static "please hold" page. Then, in your before script, to put the site into maintenance mode, you just touch the file. In your after script, rm it.

Example:

```
RewriteCond /path/to/maintmode -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintpage.htm?frompage=$1 [L]
```

So, to put your app in maintenance mode, do:

```
touch /path/to/maintmode
```

To restore to live mode:

```
rm /path/to/maintmode
```

Comment: What If the maintenance page isn't just "Sorry, down for ..." but a full HTML page with CSS, Images, ...

Comment: Same thing, doesn't matter. Just use the existence of the file as the trigger for the redirect, it doesn't matter how simple/complex the target page is.